# VB 2-Dimensional Array Item comparison to image

Tags: vb.net

Why does the messagebox show "False"?

```
    Dim images(4, 4) As Image

    For rows = 0 To 4
        For columns = 0 To 4
            images(rows, columns) = My.Resources.kaboom
        Next
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(images(3, 3).Equals(My.Resources.kaboom))
```

Comment: `My.Resources` is a Factory. It builds a new object each time you ask for one. Assign the `Resources` object to a single `Image` before the loop, then compare again.

Comment: You should generally only access a property of `My.Resources` once for each context, e.g. within a form, and then use the same object repeatedly.  If you need to use these images in more than one place or more than one time in the same place then you should declare a field, i.e. member variable, and assign the resource property value to that, then use that field each time you need that `Image`.  In your code, you are creating 26 `Image` objects that all contain exactly the same data but are still distinct objects.  For a reference type like `Image` equality means referring to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code behind the kaboom property, you will see it creates a new object every time.

```
    '''<summary>
    '''  Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
    '''</summary>
    Friend ReadOnly Property kaboom() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Get
            Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("kaboom", resourceCulture)
            Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
        End Get
    End Property
```

If you keep a reference to one object, it will be equal to true. It might also be faster since it doesn't need to create a new object.

```
    Dim kaboom As Image = My.Resources.kaboom
    Dim images(4, 4) As Image

    For rows = 0 To 4
        For columns = 0 To 4
            images(rows, columns) = kaboom
        Next
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(images(3, 3).Equals(kaboom))
```

Maybe you are already planning on doing this but here is a suggestion. If you are creating some sort of game, separate the display from the game logic. This mean, save the type of tile instead of the image and compare that. Later, you can add a bunch of different properties to a tile.

```
    Const TYPE_KABOOM As Integer = 1

    Dim tileType(4, 4) As Integer

    For rows = 0 To 4
        For columns = 0 To 4
            tileType(rows, columns) = TYPE_KABOOM
        Next
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(tileType(3, 3).Equals(TYPE_KABOOM))
```